# Unable to set AWS API Gateway response to 400 / 500

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I've a lambda that retursn the result as

```
{
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "Response": "Invalid payload sent"
}
```

or

```
{
    "StatusCode": 500,
    "Response": "Internal server error"
}
```

if something goes wrong... (otherwise it returs 200 plus an ID message inside response).

Now I'm unable to set the regex on the API so it returns the correct status code.. it always returns 200.

I've set it as `.*Invalid payload sent.*`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up a 5xx-type on *Method Response* and **then** you would be able to add & map a 5xx-type on your *Integration Response*.

See image: [awsapigateway-response-mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j4QT.png)

[Source: AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)

Other places where this has been addressed:
https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/api-gateway-integration-response-setup-for-aws-lambda-25km